# Using Google Maps to store custom set of locations (iOS Google Maps SDK)

Tags: ios, google-maps, geolocation

Create mobile application, which gives the user ability to look for certain places (payment terminals) nearby and to add new ones. Of course user will have ability to edit places, change some of their meta-info fields, add photos, etc.

I can understand, how to implement such things at the mobile device side(i mean interface and model), but can't imagine, what i have to do at the "google-side" to store locations and get them to device.

I'm looking through developers.google.com for appropriate service, but google have so much different "Maps" services and their variety makes me disappointed, which one can give me necessary instruments.

I'm sorry, if my question is too stupid but i can't realize how to implement such functionality.

If anybody ever made such applications, please help me to find, at least, the service, which can help me to implement such functionality. Sample code at github will be the great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking to build a "back-end" or a database to store the locations that you are interested in.  This means that you will save them on a server, that you will access through requests over the internet from your iPhone.

For a really simple back-end to set up, check out [Parse](http://www.parse.com/) that is very simple to implement.

Comment: you are right, but i'm trying to find something "inside" gmaps to store geodata.
for example, foursquare lets users to create their own places.

Comment: They likely just store that data and reference it along with google data. However you can either use google map maker to add locations to the map or join their partner program to get access to their API for doing so http://www.google.com/help/maps/mapcontent/

Comment: @SergeyLem have you figured this out?

Comment: yes, i'm sorry for my absence. thanks for the advice of using Parse. I 've found it very useful for my purposes.

Comment: Awesome. I'm happy it helped! If you wouldn't mind, could you mark this as the correct answer? :)